# Absolute position (component on component) - how to make it responsive? Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to make my page responsive, on a smaller screen.

I haven't used bootsrtap for this, here is how it is now. Probably I should but not sure if I can :
Is it possible to use bootstrap for this absolute positioning?

Thanks a lot, I hope it s clear enough with the drawings

```
<div class="container-map">
        <div class="top-container">
            <div class="map-background">

            </div>
            <div class="map-filter">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="map-search-results">

        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css

```
.top-container{
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

.map-background {
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.map-filter {
  z-index: 1000;
  top:5%;
  left:7%;
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:200px;
  position: absolute;
}
.map-search-results{
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

And here is what I would like:

[image]

Comment: Just leverage media queries. You don't really need to use Bootstrap for this, unless you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful.

```css
   body, html{
      padding:0;
      margin:0;
    }
   .top-container{
   height:100%;
   position:relative;
}

.map-background {
  z-index: 10;
 width:100%;
 height: 500px;
  background:lightblue;
}
.map-filter {
  z-index: 1000;
  top:5%;
  left:7%;
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:200px;
  position: absolute;
  border:5px solid red;
}
.map-search-results{
    padding:20px;
    border:5px solid orange;
}
@media (max-width:767px){
  .map-filter{
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding:20px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container-map">
      <div class="top-container">
          <div class="map-background">

          </div>
          <div class="map-filter">
            <h2>map filetr</h2>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="map-search-results">
        <h2>map search</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.map-bg {
  background: url('https://www.ryansleeper.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Tableau-Sales-by-State-Symbol-Map-with-Background-Map.png');
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 100px 20px;
}

.key-results {
  padding: 40px 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .map-bg {
    background: none !important;
    padding: 40px 20px !important;
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<section class="map-bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-12">
          <p>
            What is Lorem Ipsum?
            <br>
            <br>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="key-results">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
          <p>
            What is Lorem Ipsum?
            <br>
            <br>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need that map background on small devices just remove the media query.. Hope it'd help :)